# Cannot remove remaining drupal 8 default CSS stylesheets

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm trying to find out why I cannot remove the remaining drupal 8 default stylesheets. I'm currently using `libraries-override` to omit the necessary stylesheets inside `.info.yml file`

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/align.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css: false  
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/fieldgroup.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/container-inline.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/clearfix.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/details.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/hidden.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/item-list.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/js.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/nowrap.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/position-container.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/progress.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/reset-appearance.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/resize.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/sticky-header.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-counter.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-report-counters.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-report-general-info.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tabledrag.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tablesort.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tree-child.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.module.css: false
        /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/core.css: false
        /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/button.css: false
        /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/resizable.css: false
        /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/dialog.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/views/views.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/tour/tour.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.toolbar.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.menu.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.icons.theme.css: false
        /core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
        /core/themes/seven/css/components/quickedit.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.icons.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.icons.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/user/user.icons.admin.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/shortcut/shortcut.theme.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/shortcut/shortcut.icons.theme.css: false
```

Below are the remaining drupal 8 default stylsheets. Despite adding them inside the `libraries-override` I cannot seem to omit them. I've already tried clearing the cache

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.module.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/core.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/button.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/resizable.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/dialog.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.module.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/views/views.module.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.module.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/tour/tour.module.css?ozteii" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.toolbar.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.menu.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.icons.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/seven/css/components/quickedit.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/quickedit/quickedit.icons.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.icons.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/user/user.icons.admin.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/shortcut/shortcut.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/barebones/core/themes/stable/css/shortcut/shortcut.icons.theme.css?ozteii" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what's needed in the .info.yml file:

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18914468)

Comment: this is all you need to add inside .info.yml file to get those system resources to be removed, which I think if they try this code in their file the problem will be solved